# Unable to add xml node using .modify if Target xml contains default namespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, insert

here I need to insert source xml node into the target xml using .modify function in SQL server. Everything goes fine to the extent when I have all named namespaces. Moment I change one of the namespace to default it stops inserting the node.

Following is the code for my problem

```
Declare @sourceXML xml
Declare @TargetXML xml
Declare @tempXML xml

Set @TargetXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Message>
<MainBody>
</MainBody>
<Part>
<InnerBody xmlns:ac="http://www.example.org/Standards/1" xmlns:rlc="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</InnerBody>
</Part>
</Message>';


set @sourceXML = '<rlc:Movement xmlns:rlc="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" Type="outstanding">
  <rlc:Amt Ccy="GBP" >500000.00</rlc:Amt>
</rlc:Movement>
<rlc:Movement xmlns:rlc="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" Type="previous">
  <rlc:Amt Ccy="GBP" >0.00</rlc:Amt>
</rlc:Movement>
<rlc:Movement xmlns:rlc="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" Type="loss">
  <rlc:Amt Ccy="GBP" >1000000.00</rlc:Amt>
</rlc:Movement>
<rlc:Movement xmlns:rlc="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" Type="current">
  <rlc:Amt Ccy="GBP" >500000.00</rlc:Amt>
</rlc:Movement>
'


SET @TargetXML.modify('
declare namespace rlc= "http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard";
declare namespace ac="http://www.example.org/Standards/1" ;
declare namespace xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

insert sql:variable("@sourceXML") as first into (/Message/Part/InnerBody)[1]')
Select @TargetXML
go
```

This gives the result as follows

```
<Message>
  <MainBody />
  <Part>
    <InnerBody xmlns:ac="http://www.example.org/Standards/1" xmlns:rlc="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <rlc:Movement xmlns:rlc="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" Type="outstanding">
        <rlc:Amt Ccy="GBP">500000.00</rlc:Amt>
      </rlc:Movement>
      <rlc:Movement xmlns:rlc="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" Type="previous">
        <rlc:Amt Ccy="GBP">0.00</rlc:Amt>
      </rlc:Movement>
      <rlc:Movement xmlns:rlc="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" Type="loss">
        <rlc:Amt Ccy="GBP">1000000.00</rlc:Amt>
      </rlc:Movement>
      <rlc:Movement xmlns:rlc="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" Type="current">
        <rlc:Amt Ccy="GBP">500000.00</rlc:Amt>
      </rlc:Movement>
    </InnerBody>
  </Part>
</Message>
```

If I remove the rlc prefix and change the source xml to

```
Set @TargetXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Message>
<MainBody>
</MainBody>
<Part>
<InnerBody xmlns:ac="http://www.example.org/Standards/1" xmlns="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</InnerBody>
</Part>
</Message>';
```

I get

```
<Message>
  <MainBody />
  <Part>
    <InnerBody xmlns="http://www.example.org/Standards/Standard" xmlns:ac="http://www.example.org/Standards/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  </Part>
</Message>
```

Can anyone please have a look into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously, `InnerBody` was in the empty namespace. By your change, you're now declaring that it's in the `http://www.abc.org/Standards/Standard` namespace, and as such, the XPath `/Message/Part/InnerBody` no longer matches it. However, `/Message/Part/rlc:InnerBody` will:

```
SET @TargetXML.modify('
declare namespace rlc= "http://www.abc.org/Standards/Standard";
declare namespace ac="http://www.abc.org/Standards/1" ;
declare namespace xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

insert sql:variable("@sourceXML") as first into (/Message/Part/rlc:InnerBody)[1]')
Select @TargetXML
go
```

You should also note that namespace prefixes can be anything, so this query will also work:

```
SET @TargetXML.modify('
declare namespace a= "http://www.abc.org/Standards/Standard";
declare namespace b="http://www.abc.org/Standards/1" ;
declare namespace c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

insert sql:variable("@sourceXML") as first into (/Message/Part/a:InnerBody)[1]')
Select @TargetXML
go
```